# Constructing an Authentication Link in react-apollo using authToken from REST Endpoint

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

What is the best way of constructing a `link` in `react-apollo`?
I need to wait for the authentication token before creating an `authLink`.

One approach that works is

```
axios.get('/token').then((data) => {
  authLink = construct using data;
  client = construct using authLink;
  ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider={client}>
       <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
});
```

I can also do the same by putting it in an `async-await` block.
The problem in both the cases is that I cannot export `client` for use outside components. Thanks!